# Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, subscription

I apply all the solutions in the internet about this error but still i have this problem

i don't know where is the problem !!

1- i checked the link.
2- i checked the query.

(i use React-Apollo-GraphQL).

```
    const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken") || "";
      return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
          Authorization: token ? `JWT ${token}` : ""
        }
      };
    });


    const httpLink = new createHttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/',
      fetchOptions: {
        credentials: "include"
      },
    });

    const wsLink = () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
      return new WebSocketLink({
        uri: `ws://localhost:8000/graphql/`,
        options: {
          reconnect: true,
          timeout: 30000,
          connectionParams: {
            Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
            authToken: token
          }
        }
      });
    };

    const link = split(
      ({ query }) => {
        const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
        return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
      },
      wsLink(),
      authLink.concat(httpLink),
      )


    const client = new ApolloClient({
      link,
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      clientState: {
        defaults: {
          isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("authToken")
        }
      },
    })
```

can you help me please

Thank you.

---

** Note When i use this code(below) it work successful.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql/",
  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: "include"
  },
  request: operation => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken") || "";
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `JWT ${token}`
      }
    });
  },
  clientState: {
    defaults: {
      isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("authToken")
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`apollo-boost` does not support configuring the `link` or `cache` options for its client. [These](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/apollo-boost/src/index.ts#L29-L46) are the only supported configuration options. If you're passing in some other parameter, you should be seeing a warning your console about it.

If you need to customize your ApolloClient instance, you need to [migrate to using the full client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/boost-migration/).

Comment: What about WebSocketLink how can added with ApolloClient ?

Answer (score -1):

Restarting my mac solved the issue !